# I'm trying to download Pygame but on the final step I always get this error:

Tags: python, installation, pygame

I'm following a tutorial and the code fails on this step:

[image: This is the step that the error occurs]

Could anyone help me resolve this issue?

```
 Running setup.py install for pygame ... error

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/qm/sfjznj095bq302mwh7l2x9pm0000gn/T/pip-req-build-89d5f4tl/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/qm/sfjznj095bq302mwh7l2x9pm0000gn/T/pip-req-build-89d5f4tl/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/qm/sfjznj095bq302mwh7l2x9pm0000gn/T/pip-record-64mzuebk/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: /private/var/folders/qm/sfjznj095bq302mwh7l2x9pm0000gn/T/pip-req-build-89d5f4tl/
```

Comment: [Pygame not compatible with MacOS Mojave #555](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/issues/555)

Answer (score -1):

You can install in this way:
pip install pygame

Comment: This is a comment, but not an answer.